# Eloquent - Eager loading the inverse

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

The main problem is that I need to eager load based upon dynamic tables.  I need to find a way to produce an eloquent command that can yield me a collection in the following way..

- Outside Diameter

  - Material

    - Manufacture Part Number
    - Manufacture Part Number
    - Manufacture Part Number
    - Manufacture Part Number
- Outside Diameter

  - Material

    - Manufacture Part Number
    - Manufacture Part Number
    - Manufacture Part Number
    - Manufacture Part Number
  - ....

An eloquent command that I came up with that produces the non-desirable results are:

`$tinker> App\Models\ManufacturePartNumber::with('outsideDiameters', 'materials', 'measurements')->get();`

Which yields the following collection, given my relationships:

- Manufacture Part Number

  - Outside Diameter

    - Material
- Manufacture Part Number

  - Outside Diameter

    - Material
- Manufacture Part Number

  - Outside Diameter

    - Material
  - ....

While playing around in tinker, I attempted to run this command which made since to me.  It produces an error, which I half expected.

`$tinker> App\Models\OutsideDiameter::with('materials', 'manufacturePartNumbers')->get();
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\RelationNotFoundException with message 'Call to undefined relationship [materials] on model [App\Models\OutsideDiameter].'`

Ultimately, my problem is that I need to build an eloquent command that can eager load the results in the desired way.  The command will be dynamic, from the stance, that the model relationships are based upon a user's interaction with the site.  Think something like Amazon with checkbox filters on the left side.  The way that I see that is that I'd need to come up with every possible combination of models and create the corresponding pivot tables with all that data.  That doesn't seem efficient to me...

Any ideas on how I can get to my goal?

My given models are defined as the following:

```
class ManufacturePartNumber extends Eloquent  
{  
  public function materials()  
  {  
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\Material::class);  
  }   

  public function outsideDiameters()  
  {  
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\OutsideDiameter::class);  
  }  
}

class Material extends Eloquent  
{  
  public function manufacturePartNumbers()  
  {  
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\ManufacturePartNumber::class);  
  }   
}

class OutsideDiameter extends Eloquent  
{  
  public function manufacturePartNumbers()  
  {  
    return $this->belongsToMany(\App\Models\ManufacturePartNumber::class);  
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can eager load relationships of relationships. IE: `OutsideDiameter::with('manufacturePartNumbers', 'manufacturePartNumbers.materials')->get()`

You can also dynamically load relationships, just pass the variable holding them to the with.

```
$relationships = ['materials', 'materials.manufacturePartNumbers'];
ManufacturePartNumber::with($relationships)->get();
```

So you can add to the relationships array as needed. Does this help?

Comment: I thinks that puts me on a good path. Before I mark it as correct, I’ll see how I can constrain aspects of the ‘with’ statements.  For example, constrain material to id=3 and paginate the manufacturePartNumbers.

Comment: That's a little more rough on eloquent. Since Collection::where('manufacturePartNumbers.materials', 3) will work, the EloquentQueryBuilder::with('manufacturePartNumbers.materials')->where('manufacturePartNumbers.materials', 3) will not work. You'd almost have to build a broader query and use collections to filter it down that way.

Comment: By returning a large dataset from the database and performing a filter(s) on the collection, wouldn't that have a negative impact on overall performance?

Comment: It would, but I think it would depend more on just how big the data set is. As long as you eager load and avoid looping over a dataset that would cause PHP to struggle you should be fine. Sounds like you're going to use pagination which should alleviate those problems.

Comment: I've arrived at the office.  @n-mahurin, your  provided example `OutsideDiameter::with('manufacturePartNumbers', 'manufacturePartNumbers.materials')->get()`

Does not perform the correct nesting of the collection.  It produces OutsideDiameters->ManufacturePartNumbers->Materials.  Im striving for the 'results to be OutsideDiameters->Materials->ManufacturePartNumbers.

Comment: You would need a relationship between OutsideDiameters and Materials to have that kind of nesting.

Answer (score 0):

As I discovered during the process, Eloquent does not allow you to query for a relationship that doesn't exist.  This problem uses three tables and corresponding pivot tables in an attempt to make it work.  Even with Eloquent's hasManyThrough, it only works with at most three tables.

Ultimately, I couldn't make something out of nothing.  My solution was that I'm saddled with the N+1 problem.